# AngularJS <select> ng-options selected value is not properly set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this pseudo code angularjs app. You can select a hobby for each person, save it and load it again.
However when I load the data, the select boxes dont have the correct option selected. `person.hobby` exists and is the correct object, but it looks like ng-model isn't set correctly. 
Am I missing something?

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
    <p>{{ person.fullname }}</p>
    <select ng-model="person.hobby"
            ng-options="h.hobby_name group by h.category for h in hobbies">
    </select>
</div>

<script>

     //... controller...

     $http.get('/gethobbies/').succes(data) {
        hobbies = data;
     };

    $http.get('/getpeople/').succes(data) {
        people = data;
        // looks like this:  [{'fullname': 'bill gates', 'hobby': {'hobby_name': 'programming', 'category': 'computers'}, ...]
    };
</script>
```

Comment: If you want your problem fixed, provide a plunker example and someone will fix it for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` needs to be set to the exact same object as the one in the `ng-options` array that you want to be selected. Angular uses object references to figure out which one should be active so having a "hobby-object" with the same "hobby_name" as one of the objects in "hobbies" is not enough. It needs to be a reference to the same object.

See [documentation for select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) for details

Comment: Alright thanks. If people are wondering, I fixed it by doing a `forEach` on the `people` array, finding the reference in the `hobbies` array (the hobby with the same hobby_name) and reassigning it